# Silverlight MenuItem icon only loads image if image already loaded

Tags: silverlight, icons, contextmenu, menuitem

I have some code which used to work and now doesn't (don't know if it's SL4 -> SL5 or some other update that caused this).

I'm creating MenuItems on the fly for a right-click menu and I'm assigning the icon like so:

```
public static class XamlUtility
   {
        public static string makeResourcePngUri(string sName)
        {
            return "/MyApplication;component/Resources/" + sName + ".png";
        }

        public static BitmapImage getBitmapImageFromResources(string sName)
        {
            BitmapImage _bmi = null;
            _bmi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(makeResourcePngUri(sName), UriKind.Relative));

            return _bmi;
        }

        public static Image getImageFromResources(string sName)
        {
            Image _im = new Image();
            _im.Source = getBitmapImageFromResources(sName);

            return _im;
        }
    }

   public static class XamlUtility
   {
        public static string makeResourcePngUri(string sName)
        {
            return "/MyApplication;component/Resources/" + sName + ".png";
        }

        public static BitmapImage getBitmapImageFromResources(string sName)
        {
            BitmapImage _bmi = null;
            _bmi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(makeResourcePngUri(sName), UriKind.Relative));

            return _bmi;
        }

        public static Image getImageFromResources(string sName)
        {
            Image _im = new Image();
            _im.Source = getBitmapImageFromResources(sName);

            return _im;
        }
    }
...
        public static MenuItem addMenuItem(ContextMenu ctxmenu, string name, bool visible = true, MenuClickHandler clickHandler = null, string imageName = null)
        {
            string _name = name.Replace(' ', '_');
            MenuItem menu = new MenuItem()
            {
                Name = "mnu" + _name,
                Header = name,
                Icon = XamlUtility.getImageFromResources(imageName ?? _name)
            };
```

...

The image only loads if I have it previously loaded (e.g. create an image control on some xaml form prior to generating the ContextMenu).

This used to work (it wasn't a high priority to fix so I don't know when it stopped working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your getBitmapImageFromResources method add

```
_bmi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly (though still confused as to why I never needed this before and why it's only in my context menu I need this).

Comment: I don't know why exactly.  If I get some free time I'll give it a more indepth look.  Glad it worked for you. Think you could mark it as answered?

Comment: Oops...sorry about that (the answered part).

Only mildly curious. It's working (and I'm only using the ignorecache for the instances where it didn't work just in case there's a performance benefit).